# How to network boot a laptop?

Tags: windows-7, pxe

I have Windows 7 on a CD-ROM and downloaded as an ISO image. I need to reinstall Windows on a HP Mini 311 - 1000NR laptop which has no CD-ROM drive. In the BIOS I have the option to network boot or boot from a USB drive.

I don't own a USB drive large enough to house Windows so I'm left with the network boot option.

How can I install Windows 7 from the network?  I have a Windows XP laptop and an Ethernet network on a router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some server type imaging solution I don't see network install working out very well.  I would look at an install from hard disk tutorial like [this](http://www.w7forums.com/install-windows-7-hard-disk-t163.html).  That's just what I would do in your situation.

Comment: I bought an external CD-ROM drive.  I used your answer regarding difficulty to help determine my choice.

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide here: [How to Install Vista on a M200 Without a CD Drive Using TFTP](http://blog.ryantadams.com/2008/02/01/how-to-boot-from-the-network-pxe-boot-with-tftp-and-windows-pe/)

Following that looks like it should do what you are after, and should equally apply to Windows 7.